# Does a variable override method here

Tags: python, function, variables, hide

I am starting to play around with python a little, and as a novice i tried this:

```
>>> s="";str=""
>>> for x in [ 1,2,3,4,5,6 ] : 
...   s += str(x)
...   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I accidentally declared a variable called `str` (str is supposed to be a function).

- Assuming it would break the semantics too much, even in a dynamically
  typed language, is there a namespace i can use to qualify methods
  like `str` and ensure this does not happen or make it difficult?

Comment: You can't prevent this, it's just something you need to be aware of when coding in Python.

Comment: @Simon: Can i import all standard functions in a module of my own?

Comment: They're already there whenever you write Python code. Built-in functions are already imported.

Comment: @Simon: I mean can i wrap them in my own module just like namespaces?There must be a way to prevent name clashes...because it is not possible to remember all the functions that python provides and make sure not to have same named variables; especially if the function names are short and like `str`.

Comment: As mentioned before this isn't possible in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `import <module>` instead of `from <module> import *` is used for.  As long as you use str in the only meaning of local variable value in `<module>`, you can use
`module.str` elswhere, without mangling namespace.

The only tokens that can't be clashed are  [keywords](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). This is intended functionality and there is no way to prevent this: [everything is an object in Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html)

You might want to use some IDE tools, p.ex. Eclipse+PyDev, that checks your code and warn for possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you have already defined

```
str=""
```

so when you will call str method which converts values into string it will not call actual method in place of that it will call `str=""`.
that's why you are getting error because you can not call a str object to convert int to string.

Comment: I understand that, i am asking is there an easy way to prevent name clashes.